# Sequelize.Utils._? OR Lodash?

Tags: sequelize.js, lodash

Sequelize provides 1 built-in lodash utility as **"Sequelize.Utils._"**, then why we install separate Lodash module? Is there any pros/cons?
[Reference link for sequelize utils](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/utils/)

Answer (score 1):

Really more of a judgement call, but if you only need the version provided by Sequelize, I would just use that. I will list some theoretical pros and cons but they are likely minimal and subjective.

Pros:

- No need to manage additional dependency
- Single Lodash dependency, smaller disk space footprint (if your project uses a different version than Sequelize npm will download both versions)

Cons:

- Sequelize doesn't necessarily have the latest version of Lodash which you need because of X feature.
- You don't plan to use Sequelize forever (this could be solved by abstracting the access to Lodash).